# Does everyone from Naruto's generation have chakra within them?

Tags: naruto

I think it's feasible to imagine some people out there in the world have been born without chakra during the time period where Naruto is alive. I say this because chakra as we learn in the anime was originally given to Hagoromo Ōtsutsuki during a time period in the history of Naruto where no one had chakra, after which she passed it on to her children. Therefore it's presumable that of the other people alive at the time some of them could have continued to have children without ever mixing bloodlines with those who had chakra all the way until Naruto's generation.

Now despite this I can see how considering how many generations it has been there's not likely to be many left who haven't attained chakra, but do you think they are there, and why were they never a plot point for the show?

Comment: Are you acutely asking about people in the Hidden Village itself who didn't have chakra?  The main reason I want to put a finer point on this is that this is getting close to supposition, and I'd rather have a question based more on concrete facts in the Naruto universe.  For instance, do you know of any characters who are explicitly stated to lack chakra?

Comment: @Makoto No I don't know any characters who are explicitly stated to lack chakra as that would negate the question, nor do I necessarily expect those without chakra would be in the hidden leaf village. That said, if you want concrete facts, then you have the multiple of episodes referencing Hagoromo Otsutsuki which talked about there being no one with chakra before Hagoromo Otsutsuki was given it by the tree. If you'd like then all of those characters from Hagoromo Otsutsuki's time could be considered to explicitly lack chakra.

Answer (score 2):

I don't blame you for asking this question. It is hard to imagine how everyone could have chakra if Kaguya was the origin of chakra, and only a few people had actually descended from Kaguya. But there are some fillers that you have not seen that will explain how.

In one of the late Shippuden episodes, we see Asura Otsusuki, the grandson of Kaguya, teach a bunch of people ninjutsu while he was on a mission to supposedly find water. I think he spread chakra by "donating" it to people. It's either that or everyone has a chakra flow that was unnoticed before Kaguya, and she activated the chakra flow and started the concept of shinobi.

Comment: Didn't the sage of the six paths also travel the world to teach people about chakra and ninshu?

Comment: @Gravinco Yes he did. Though it was shown in the anime as filler, it was cannonicaly confirmed by Hagoromo himself about how he taught his sons and others Ninshu, which required chakra to fully work. "Hagoromo exemplified his teachings by distributing chakra meant to "connect" people's spiritual energies with one another. It would allow people to understand each other without communication" and " Indra Ōtsutsuki was the first to weaponise it into ninjutsu, Others followed his footsteps". When only 4 people alive were Ōtsutsuki, Others were using chakra.

Comment: The last bit of that answer seems a little convoluted. Is it definite that we should be assuming that everyone had an innate chakra flow before Kaguya and/or that people can donate chakra? Or is it still open ended as to whether everyone gained access to chakra and there could be a, dare I say it, Boruto episode where this is developed further?